# How to set up blog alerts in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to set up a blog subscription alert using SharePoint 2010. How to do this?

I want to create a blog and should be able to save it in SharePoint site, if the user click for blog subscription then it should be able to invoke an alert to the their mail!

How it is possible to do?? can anyone please consult me or provide at-least any right tutorial link?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if on the default homepage, click the 'alert me' link below the posts, right under the 'RSS Feed' link... [see here](http://www.glynblogs.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/SharePoint-2010-Blog-Site-Template.png)